# How to make this simple json work in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a simple form with 4 inputs that I need to dynamically add the placeholder into.

I think i understand the general idea of json, but I'm not sure how to make this work. Can someone please help me?

```
var inputArray = [
    {"inputClass":"name","placeholder":"Your Name*"},
    {"inputClass":"phone","placeholder":"Your Phone*"},
    {"inputClass":"email","placeholder":"Your Email*"},
    {"inputClass":"message","placeholder":"Your Message*"}
];
$.each(inputArray, function(i, inputClass, placeholder) {
    $('form').find('input.'+inputArray[i].inputClass).attr("placeholder", inputArray[i].placeholder);
});​
```

Comment: Works, but you do not need of `function(i, inputClass, placeholder)` but `function(i)`

Comment: @AlexBall correct signature for `.each()` callback is `function(index,element) { ... }` while `function(i) {...}` will give index only.

Comment: @Strelok ok, but he use only inputArray[i] the index to access to value... but ok, correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code, except your signature for the `.each(...)` callback is a bit wrong. It should be `function(index,element) { ... }`. But your code works anyway. Cleaner way to write your code would be:

```
var inputArray = [
    {"inputClass":"name","placeholder":"Your Name*"},
    {"inputClass":"phone","placeholder":"Your Phone*"},
    {"inputClass":"email","placeholder":"Your Email*"},
    {"inputClass":"message","placeholder":"Your Message*"}
];

$.each(inputArray, function(i, item) {
    $('form').find('input.'+item.inputClass).attr("placeholder", item.placeholder);
});​
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RQAJA/